# Keep iCloud from syncing tags across machines?

Tags: macos, icloud, finder-tag

I recently upgraded to OS X 10.9 (Yay!), and I've been playing with Tags. After I installed it on a second machine, though, I noticed that all my tags were synced across (just the list of tags, not the actual documents).

The problem with this is that I'd like to have a different set of tags on each machine. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Apart from the obvious "use different iCloud accounts" solution?

Comment: Yes, I'd really like to try to keep all my family devices on one main account. I have a spare to play with, if you have a clever solution.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no setting for selective tag syncing through iCloud. Any tag that is either created, deleted, enabled, or disabled is automatically synced to all computers on that iCloud account.